# Copy an array or remove unsatisfied condition key from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to copy an array to another array which satisfies certain condition..in some cases it works but som case not.please check the below code

```
if($params['search_params']['inv_days_start'] != '') {
            $res = array();

            if(!empty($result)) {
                foreach($result as $key=>$r) {

                    if($params['search_params']['inv_days_is'] == 'less_equal') {

                        if($r['date_diff'] <= $params['search_params']['inv_days_start']) {
                            $res[$key] = $result[$key];
                        }
                    } else if($params['search_params']['inv_days_is'] == 'greater_equal') {

                        if($r['date_diff'] >= $params['search_params']['inv_days_start']) {
                            $res[$key] = $result[$key];
                        }
                    } else if($params['search_params']['inv_days_is'] == 'is') {

                        if($r['date_diff'] == $params['search_params']['inv_days_start']) {
                            $res[$key] = $result[$key];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $res[$key] = $result[$key];
                    }
                }
            }

            return $res;
        }
```

i applied this for scroll pagination but sometimes it shows empty result..please help me

Comment: hello, what cases work and what not work?

Comment: Debugging: Add an 'else' to every if statement and echo the value when it enters the 'else' part. Also, report if '$result' is empty while you are 'debugging'.

Comment: Hi friends, thank you for spent time for me..it was actually the issue of scroll pagination.i have fixed it.thanks again